# add incrementing numbers per day to a table

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table with a datestamp. I want to add a column to number the records but they have to restart every day. Is this possible?

**Example:**

```
+------------------+--------------+
| Date             | Data         |
+------------------+--------------+
| 19-10-2017 10:18 | Transaction1 |
| 19-10-2017 12:18 | Transaction2 |
| 19-10-2017 13:23 | Transaction3 |
| 20-10-2017 11:18 | Transaction4 |
| 20-10-2017 14:18 | Transaction5 |
| 21-10-2017 09:18 | Transaction6 |
| 21-10-2017 10:18 | Transaction7 |
| 21-10-2017 11:18 | Transaction8 |
| 21-10-2017 12:18 | Transaction9 |
+------------------+---------+----+
```

**And I want this:**

```
+------+------------------+--------------+
| Nr   | Date             | Data         |
+------+------------------+--------------+
|    1 | 19-10-2017 10:18 | Transaction1 |
|    2 | 19-10-2017 12:18 | Transaction2 |
|    3 | 19-10-2017 13:23 | Transaction3 |
|    1 | 20-10-2017 11:18 | Transaction4 |
|    2 | 20-10-2017 14:18 | Transaction5 |
|    1 | 21-10-2017 09:18 | Transaction6 |
|    2 | 21-10-2017 10:18 | Transaction7 |
|    3 | 21-10-2017 11:18 | Transaction8 |
|    4 | 21-10-2017 12:18 | Transaction9 |
+------+------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: do you want to update the table by adding new column or just want to print in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution:

```
SELECT 
    @row_number:=CASE WHEN DATE(@date_value)=DATE(`Date`) THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,
    @date_value:=`Date` AS `Date`
FROM test, (SELECT @row_number:=0, @date_value:=DATE(NULL)) AS t
ORDER BY `Date`, row_number
```

Comment: I’d store the DATE() as the variable